# Составить запрос к БД на MYSQL: сравнение и обновление

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Я не силён в составлении сложных запросах, обещаю исправиться. Сейчас хочу попросить у вас помощи в составлении запроса.

В моём распоряжении 2 таблицы. 
cms3***_object*****contet (её то мы и будем апдейтить)
и price**imp ( а вот из неё брать значения).

Структура price_imp
[image: img1]

Структура content
[image: img2]

Мне необходимо следующее:
Найти объекты с одинаковым obj***_***_id и varchar***_***val
из price__imp, взять varchar_val, и посмотреть к какому field_id относится это значение в cms3_oject_content. Если field_id 484, то нужно значение из price_imp.float_val обновить  в cms3_object_content.float_val с field_id 268
если 485 то 467
486 то 468 ...

Comment: честно вообще не понял что откуда обновлять, попробуйте поподробнее и понятливей объяснить) особенно не понятны условия 268 если 485 то 467 486 то 468 ...

Тем более странно  что в талб  cms3_object_content поле float_val указывает на на 288 при fied_id=483

Comment: Это карточка объекта. Привязка идет следующая. Код товара с varchar_val c field_id 484 имеет привязку к весу float_val с fiel_id 467. А 485 varchar_val к 468 float_val и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно вам поможет ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE если я правильно вас понял